# Does elixir Enum or any other module have group_by function similar to ruby's group_by

Tags: elixir

Ruby has this awesome method [group_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) for Enumerable. Does Elixir have something similar? I could not find this functionality on the Enum module. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of [group_by/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) in Enum module.

Grouping an array of strings based on its length:

```
iex(12)> ["ant", "buffalo", "cat", "dingo"] |>  Enum.group_by(&String.length/1)

         %{3 => ["cat", "ant"], 5 => ["dingo"], 7 => ["buffalo"]}
```

From the docs:

> Splits collection into groups based on a *fun*.
>
> The result is a dict (by default a map) where each key is a group and each value is a list of elements from collection for which fun returned that group. Ordering is not necessarily preserved.

Answer (score 4):

Not yet. We haven't added it because we were waiting on maps. It will be added to the v0.13 branch. :)

*** UPDATE ***
For anyone who didn't notice the comment below, it has now been added.